# How to decode .lzo_deflat file?

Tags: python, unix, command-line, hadoop, compression

does anyone have either a command-line or python library that can decode a .lzo_deflate file?  These file formats are used by Hadoop, for example.

Comment: https://github.com/jd-boyd/python-lzo

Comment: You can also try the command line tool [lzop](http://www.lzop.org/) which should be available as a package in most Linux distributions.

Comment: if you need to copy data from hdfs, use hadoop dfs -text <file>

Comment: lzop command line tool doesn't seem to work on ".lzo_deflate files". Is there any other way to decompress it?

Answer (score 1):

Google for Python LZO, and check your linux distribution for `lzop`:

Many Linux distributions (e.g. Debian, Ubuntu) will have this:

```
liblzo2-2 - data compression library
liblzo2-dev - data compression library (development files)
lzop - fast compression program
python-lzo - Python bindings for the LZO data compression library
```

Answer (score 0):

For the windows' folks:

- Python Extension Packages for Windows - Christoph Gohlke : http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-lzo